# I resized my /boot partition and broke GRUB

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2

I used a Live USB and GParted to resize my boot partition. Now my ThinkPad is booting to a `grub>` prompt and I'm realizing I have no idea what to do.

As suggested [in another thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot), I tried just typing "exit" and return but that takes me in a little boot circle back to the grub prompt.

So I tried listing the contents of each `(hd0...)`  and I can't find `/efi/boot/grub` anywhere.

`ls (hd1,gpt2)/efi` is empty. `(hd1,gpt2)` was my `/boot` partition.

`ls (hd1,gpt1)/efi/boot` includes `bootx64.efi` and `fbx64.efi` but no `grub`

What is my next step here, so I can boot to Ubuntu?

I have backups and if I lose everything I'll live but I'd rather not start from scratch.

Comment: Only when booted in your install will /boot show the files in the ESP as it is mounted in fstab. You should also have a grub.cfg in your ESP which is just a configfile entry to load full grub.cfg in your install. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: What is an ESP? There's a `grub.cfg` in `(hd1,gpt1)/efi/ubuntu`

Comment: The ESP - efi system partition is your FAT32 formatted partition with esp flag. Required for UEFI boot. Ubuntu normally has a 3 line /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg that configfile boots to full grub.cfg in your install. UUID must match and if multiple installs of Ubuntu will be from last install.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [@oldfred](https://askubuntu.com/users/126395/oldfred), I created a [Boot Repair][2] disk. Contrary to his advice, I ran the recommended repairs, but I was pretty confident that all my files were intact, including the files on the newly expanded `/boot` volume.

I think the generic solution to recommend is definitely read through [this other thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot) from *Unix & Linux* -- if that answer doesn't solve your problems, create a bootable [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) USB and boot to it.

You can decide whether your next step is to try the recommended repairs (which I did successfully but it was kind of a rogue move) or start a new question with the specifics of your broken boot loader and see if someone can guide you.