# How do I run firmware updates, if nothing happens when I click "update"?

Tags: thinkpad, firmware, gnome-software

Gnome software often shows me Device Firmware updates in the Updates tab:

[image]

Usually, clicking the "Update" button runs them. That seems like generally expected behavior. In this case, when I click update the looping arrow at the top left spins and says "Checking" for a few seconds and then the Update just re-appears on the list.

Last week I was trying to run these and getting the same behavior. I later interrupted a kernel update and assumed that my trouble booting was connected to the firmware updates. (See [Interrupted a device firmware update and now I can't boot into Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336073/interrupted-a-hardware-update-and-now-i-cant-boot-into-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment2280602_1336073)) but it seems I was wrong about that.

But now I see that actually the firmware updates are still waiting. Is there a trick to getting them to run or seeing why they haven't run? A log I should review perhaps?